# NodeJS - Request module - GET XML

Tags: node.js, xml

I am currently trying to get a XML from an external source using request / request-promise.

I did the following:

```
const request = require('request-promise');

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: '',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8',
  },
};

request(options).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

The external XML contains characters like ü,ö,ä. They are all missing and are replaced by a question mark in a box.

I thought setting the header would be enough and my google research didn't bring up any other solutions for this scenario.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks for every hint!!

Comment: The content-type **request** header describes the content of the **request** body (which doesn't exist because you are making a GET request).

Comment: Can you log the response headers? What is the _response_ content-type and charset? That is what matters. As @Quentin says request content-type isn't used for GET requests. The output could also be affected by logging to console. Try writing it to a file and opening it in some editor which handles unicode characters.

Comment: Response got a header for Content-Type: "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1" -- Idk how to deal with that tbh -- Ok just checked, this ISO code got no ü,ö,ä -- If I use a rss parser I get the characters correctly however some fields are missing...